# This database cannot be imported - error keeps showing up

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have been trying to refresh my database data to see if my database works and I get this error:

> This database cannot be imported.it is either an unsupported SQL Server version or an unsupported database compatibility

I have looked for some answers on the internet but so far I am lost and I have no idea what to do.

This is my `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
    </system.web>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="StarterSite" 
             connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\StarterSite.sdf" 
             providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>    
    </connectionStrings>
    ....
    <system.data>        
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
            <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" 
                 invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"
                 description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact"
                 type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
    ....
</configuration>
```

added my ADO Code incase it helps

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for MyAdoHelper
/// פעולות עזר לשימוש במסד נתונים  מסוג 
/// SQL SERVER
///  App_Data המסד ממוקם בתקיה 
/// </summary>

public class MyAdoHelper
{
    public MyAdoHelper()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }


    public static SqlConnection ConnectToDb(string fileName)
    {
        string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("App_Data/");//מיקום מסד בפורוייקט
        path += fileName;
        string connString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename =" + path + ";Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        return conn;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// To Execute update / insert / delete queries
    ///  הפעולה מקבלת שם קובץ ומשפט לביצוע ומבצעת את הפעולה על המסד
    /// </summary>

    public static void DoQuery(string fileName, string sql)//הפעולה מקבלת שם מסד נתונים ומחרוזת מחיקה/ הוספה/ עדכון
    //ומבצעת את הפקודה על המסד הפיזי
    {

        SqlConnection conn = ConnectToDb(fileName);
        //conn.Close();
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        com.Dispose();
        conn.Close();

    }


    /// <summary>
    /// To Execute update / insert / delete queries
    ///  הפעולה מקבלת שם קובץ ומשפט לביצוע ומחזירה את מספר השורות שהושפעו מביצוע הפעולה
    /// </summary>
    public static int RowsAffected(string fileName, string sql)//הפעולה מקבלת מסלול מסד נתונים ופקודת עדכון
    //ומבצעת את הפקודה על המסד הפיזי
    {

        SqlConnection conn = ConnectToDb(fileName);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        int rowsA = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        return rowsA;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// הפעולה מקבלת שם קובץ ומשפט לחיפוש ערך - מחזירה אמת אם הערך נמצא ושקר אחרת
    /// </summary>
    public static bool IsExist(string fileName, string sql)//הפעולה מקבלת שם קובץ ומשפט בחירת נתון ומחזירה אמת אם הנתונים קיימים ושקר אחרת
    {

        SqlConnection conn = ConnectToDb(fileName);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlDataReader data = com.ExecuteReader();
        bool found;
        found = (bool)data.Read();// אם יש נתונים לקריאה יושם אמת אחרת שקר - הערך קיים במסד הנתונים
        conn.Close();
        return found;

    }


    public static DataTable ExecuteDataTable(string fileName, string sql)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = ConnectToDb(fileName);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter tableAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        tableAdapter.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }


    public static void ExecuteNonQuery(string fileName, string sql)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = ConnectToDb(fileName);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }

    public static string printDataTable(string fileName, string sql)//הפעולה מקבלת שם קובץ ומשפט בחירת נתון ומחזירה אמת אם הנתונים קיימים ושקר אחרת
    {


        DataTable dt = ExecuteDataTable(fileName, sql);

        string printStr = "<table border='1'>";

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            printStr += "<tr>";
            foreach (object myItemArray in row.ItemArray)
            {
                printStr += "<td>" + myItemArray.ToString() + "</td>";
            }
            printStr += "</tr>";
        }
        printStr += "</table>";

        return printStr;
    }



}
```

Comment: You have a SQL Server **Compact** version defined in your `web.config` - this works with a `.sdf` database file - ***NOT*** an  `.mdf` database file! `.mdf` is the **full** (non-Compact) version of SQL Server only (you had `mdf` as a tag of yours)

Comment: @marc_s so what do i do? my database is called database.mdf

Comment: You're not showing nor explaining what you're trying to do, really - you've just posted the contents of your web.config ..... so please **explain** what you're trying to do! Then *maybe*  we can help you ...

Comment: @marc_s i am making a database for a asp.net based site. my database works ok but when i try to refresh the data on my database it shows this error. sorry if im not explaining it poorly i am not really sure what to explain and i am pretty new to this site .(do you need any more code or parts of the website for more information?)

Comment: *Refresh* - how?? In code? So please **show the code** (since we cannot see and read your screen - nor your mind). In a tool? What tool and how are you trying to do this??

Comment: @marc_s i am using visual studio and when i access the data base data table i need to hit a refresh button to see new entered data. now when i hit the refresh button it just shows this error

Comment: Your **code** is using a full SQL Server database (the `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB` connection string uses SQL Server **Express LocalDB**), while your config uses SQL Server **Compact Edition** - those two **ARE NOT** compatible. If you use the SQL Server **LocalDB**, you need to change your config to represent that!

Comment: @marc_s how do i change that im not very familiar with source codes

Answer (score 0):

Your code is using the `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB` instance which is SQL Server **Express LocalDB** - this is the **full** SQL Server - **NOT** the Compact Edition.

So you need to change your config to be something like this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
    </system.web>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="StarterSite" 
             connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|YourDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>    
    </connectionStrings>
    ....
    ....
</configuration>
```

You don't need any entries under `<system.data><DbProviderFactories>` since those are already in place in the machine-wide `machine.config` on your system.

Comment: other than what you wrote do i need to copy anything else. and if yes where do i find the code i only know basic aspx and opening a database i dont know what to do with the code you just gave me. sorry for being so annoying